# Referencing a field by string

Tags: c#, string, reflection, casting, reference

A pretty simple question, but I cant find a good answer via 25 minutes of googles~

I would like to reference an object stored in a field named (string)~

Something like~

```
private string ButtonName;
public ActionPanel ActionPanel;
private object reference;

void main(){
     ActionPanel = new ActionPanel();
     reference = ActionPanel.ChangeSelectedActionBundle.(ButtonName);

    }
```

Im assuming I will need to use reflections, but i'm not quite sure the right way of doing this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection would work like this (assuming you're trying to get the property of "ChangeSelectedActionBundle" with the name of the value of ButtonName):

```
Type type = ActionPanel.ChangeSelectedActionBundle.GetType();
PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(ButtonName);
object value = property.GetValue(ActionPanel.ChangeSelectedActionBundle, null);
```

Comment: I just want to say that I disagree with the "better syntax" suggested edit. @Burdock: You'll have a lot of work ahead of you if you plan on suggesting edits such as that! (95% of answers use `var`).

Comment: Point taken, Thanks for the help!!